# I am in the process of learning about Data Modeling using the ER diagramming method

Tags: data-modeling, visio, erd

I am in the process of learning about Data Modeling using the ER diagramming methods. Can someone please assist me on how I could handle this case.

The diagram should contain two entities, Employee and Course. The employee entity contains a PK of Employee ID and the following additional Attributes:

1. Employee Name
2. Birth Date

The Course entity contains a PK of Course ID with the following additional attributes.

1. Course Title
2. Topic

In addition, there is an attribute (property) on the relationship of Date Completed. If I wanted to keep track of which employees are notified about each course completion by an employee, what would be the proper way to model this in Visio.

Here's what I've tried so far:

[image]

Comment: Didn't think about posting a link to a screenshot. Good thinking Ken.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16711826/Employee-Courses.jpg

Comment: Thanks for posting what I have so far to this thread for me. Greatly appreciated, Ken!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this really depends on what notation you are using.  For instance, from the diagram it appears you are using a hybrid IE/IDEF1X notation.  In that notation and approach, relationships can't have attributes.  What is required in that case is to create an intersectional entity that resolves the relationship.  Sometimes this is called an associative entity or a resolution entity, too.

I'm guessing from the relation and the attribute, that your intersectional entity would be something like COURSE COMPLETION.  You'd then have something that looked like:

```
EMPLOYEE -completes----< COURSE COMPLETTION > -----completes -- COURSE
```

And COURSE COMPLETION would inherit the identifiers from each entity:

```
COURSE COMPLETION
=========================
COURSE ID (PK)
EMPLOYEE ID (PK)
DATE COMPLETED
```

Also wanted to throw in the fact that this only provides for one completion per Employee/Course pair. And that probably doesn't reflect real life.

I'm not sure I understand your additional question about notification.  Can you expand upon that?